# Angular Reactive form showing error on validation condition on production build

Tags: javascript, angular, validation, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms

Using reactive forms in Ionic application showing error on production build.

> 67: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string'
> and 'number' have no overlap.

```
[disabled]="(schedule == 2 && getAboutControl.schedule_time.errors?.required ||
 getAboutControl.schedule_date.errors?.required)"
```

my Form init:

```
initAboutForm() {
    this.aboutForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      is_schedule: ['1'], // will depend on this to make date and time required.
      schedule_date: [''],
      schedule_time: [''],
      // other values
    })
}
```

my Html:

```
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Date:</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD MMM, YYYY" min="2021" max="2030" formControlName="schedule_date">
       </ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
    <div class="text-danger">
       <div *ngIf="getAboutControl.schedule_date.touched && getAboutControl.schedule_date.errors?.required">
        Date is required *
       </div>
    </div>

   <ion-item>
     <ion-label>Time:</ion-label>
     <ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm" formControlName="schedule_time"></ion-datetime>
   </ion-item>
   <div class="text-danger">
     <div *ngIf="getAboutControl.schedule_time.touched && getAboutControl.schedule_time.errors?.required">
      Time is required *
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: schedule == 2 && (getAboutControl.schedule_time.errors?.required ||
 getAboutControl.schedule_date.errors?.required )                                                                                  And check schedule variable type string or not

Comment: @SanoojT can you explain. i have initialized both variables as string.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib If both are strings then you'd need to replace `schedule == 2` by `schedule == '2'` in the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, in the template you're comparing `schedule` (string) against `2` (number).

So the fix would be to compare `schedule` against `'2'` instead:

```
[disabled]="(schedule === '2' && getAboutControl.schedule_time.errors?.required || getAboutControl.schedule_date.errors?.required)"
```

Comment: lol what a dumb bug it was :D wasted 2 days. i changed `schedule_time` `schedule_date` unlimited times and thought it is related to them.

Comment: Yeah, these bugs are the hardest ones to find as we usually look for more complicated problems and overlook the simplest things! It happens to all of us :)